# Sequence of positive real number

Tags: real-analysis

What is an example of a positive real sequence $t_n$ that satisfies 
$\liminf t_n = 0$, $\limsup t_n > 0$ and $\lim (t_{n+1}-t_{n})=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a slightly more "formulaic" example, take $a_n = \sin^2(\ln n)$.

The fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n+1}-a_n = 0$ follows from the mean value theorem. The other two conditions should be at least intuitively clear.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following sequence (I will leave the fractions unreduced to illustrate how it works):
$$ \frac{2}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{2}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{4}{4},\frac{7}{8},\frac{6}{8},\frac{5}{8},\frac{4}{8},\frac{3}{8},\frac{2}{8},\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{16},\frac{2}{16},\frac{3}{16},\frac{4}{16},\frac{5}{16},\frac{6}{16},\frac{7}{16}\dots$$

Answer (score 0):

$a_1=0$, $a_2=1/2$, $a_3=1/2+1/3$, $a_4=1/2+1/3+1/4,\dots$ continue this until the term becomes just greater than $1$, say $a_m$ is the 1st term in the sequence greater than $1$,

$a_m=1/2+1/3+\dots+1/m$,

$a_{m+1}=(1/2+1/3+\dots+1/m)-(1/(m+1))$,  $a_{m+2}=(1/2+1/3+\dots+1/m)-(1/(m+1)+1/(m+2))$
$a_{m+3}=(1/2+1/3+\dots+1/m)-(1/(m+1)+1/(m+2)+1/(m+3))$

Continue this until the terms are greater than $0$, once the term becomes less than $0$, say $a_n<0$

then $a_{n+1}=a_n+1/(n+1)$,

$a_{n+2}=a_n+1/(n+1)+1/(n+2)$, continue this till the terms just becomes greater than $1$ and repeat the same process!

Writing in a recursion form gives:

$a_1=0$,
$a_2=1/2$

$a_{n+1}=a_n +1/(n+1$) if $\{a_n<1$ and $a_n-a_{n-1}>0\}$ Or $\{a_n<0\}$

$a_{n+1}=a_n -1/(n+1$) if $\{a_n>0$ and $a_n-a_{n-1}<0\}$ Or $\{a_n>1\}$

Answer (score 0):

$0,1,\;\frac {1}{2},0,\;$ $\frac {1}{4}, \frac {2}{4},\frac {3}{4},1,\;$ $\frac {7}{8},\frac {6}{8},\frac {5}{8},\frac {4}{8},\frac {3}{8},\frac {2}{8},\frac {1}{8},0,\;$ $\frac {1}{16}, \frac {2}{16},\;...\;,\frac {15}{16},1,\; \frac {31}{32},\frac {30}{32},\;......$